Important Email Not Showing in Gmail App's 'All Inboxes' on iPhone, how can I fix it?
I use the Gmail app on my iPhone to manage emails from five different Gmail accounts. Generally, the app works well, allowing me to read all incoming emails in the "All Inboxes" section.
However, a company recently informed me that they had sent an important email which I had not replied to. Upon checking, I discovered that this email was not visible in the "All Inboxes" section. Later, I found it marked as unread in the "All Mail" folder of the specific account.
Please check the screenshot below:

Why is this happening? Is there a setting that filters which emails appear in "All Inboxes"?
How can I ensure that all my emails are visible in the "All Inboxes" section?
Thanks!

This is more likely a Google mail issue and not an Apple issue.
